# Why C++11 std::sort() is not faster when sorting std::string?

Tags: string, sorting, c++11, move, swap

std::sort() uses swap() to swap elements, where swap now in C++11 uses "move()" semantics in swap() to avoid copy.

I think this is especially useful for std::string. So I designed an experiment to check this out:

> 1. I constructed a vector of 10240000 elements(std::string), these elements are constructed by randomString() function.
> 2. Use std::sort to sort out all elements, and print out time duration.

```
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
string randomString()
{
    int iBuf[10];
    for(size_t i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        double rand0to1=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        iBuf[i]=rand0to1*92+33;
    }
    char ret[6];
    snprintf(ret, 6, "%c%c%c%c%c\n",
        iBuf[0],iBuf[1],iBuf[2],iBuf[3],iBuf[4]);
    return ret;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    const size_t scale=10240000;
    vector<string> vs;
    vs.reserve(scale);
    for(size_t i=0;i<scale;++i)
    {
        vs.push_back(randomString());
    }
    cout<<vs.size()<<"End vector construction\n";
    clock_t begin=clock();
    sort(vs.begin(),vs.end());
    clock_t end=clock();
    double duration=(double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout<<"sort "<<scale<<"Time elapse="<<duration<<"seconds\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the strings are small they're probably using SBO, which does not benefit from move semantics. Try with long strings.

Comment: I don't really see a *question* here? What results do you get? What did you expect? What are you comparing the results to?

Comment: This is a case where std::stable_sort (based on merge sort) might be faster than std:sort (based on quick sort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where swap now in C++11 uses "move()" semantics in swap() to avoid copy.

That is what the non-specialized/non-overloaded swap() now does. There has been an overload [`std::swap(std::basic_string)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/swap2) since before C++11 and it has never needed to copy the memory buffer of either argument string.

> I think this is especially useful for std::string

Because of what I said in the last paragraph, `std::string` in particular is a case where move semantics introduce no advantage to swapping.

The generic move based swap is probably good enough for many use cases and it allows an efficient swap for a custom movable type without requiring you to specialize swap. But a specialized swap can still be (possibly only marginally) more efficient.

> Why C++11 std::sort() is not faster when sorting std::string?

Because the generic move based swap offers no advantage over the specialized swap that already existed.